# OpenCV Histogram Matching/Specification

Tags: c++, histogram, opencv3.0

I have two gray scale images, and I want to copy the histogram of one image to the other. Since I'm working with OpenCv, I've tried both this method [histogram recoloring](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/01/28/recoloring-via-histogram-matching-with-opencv-w-code/) and this [histogram for gray scale images](http://answers.opencv.org/question/50678/histogram-specificationfittingmatching/). The first link gives me no results, while the second return this image:
Reference Image:
[image: Reference Image]
Input Image:
[image: Input Image]
Result Image:
[image: Result image]

According to the code of the grayscale histogram matching, I had to implement the cumsum and ScanImageAndReduceC function:

```
cumsum:
for (size_t i = 0; i < X.rows; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < X.cols; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                result.at<double>(i, j) = X.at<double>(i, j);
            }
            else
            {
                result.at<double>(i, j) = X.at<double>(i, j) + result.at<double>(i, j - 1);
            }
        }

    }
```

while the other functin was picked from here: [how to scan images](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html).

How can I succesfully copy the histogram of one image to another?
I'm using OpenCV 3.1
Thank!

Comment: @Miki I mean to take the histogram of an image and applying it to another image!

Comment: @Miki I mean that after the procedure both images have the same histogram!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to solve the problem,and I find the bug in your function "cumsum".The function of "cumsum" should  be written as :

```
Mat cumsum (Mat & src) 
{
  Mat result = Mat::zeros(Size(src.cols,src.rows),CV_32FC1);      
  for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; ++i) 
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; ++j)
     {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            result.at<float>(i, j) = src.at<float>(i, j);
         }
         else
         {
             result.at<float>(i, j) = src.at<float>(i, j) + result.at<float>(i-1, j);
         }               

       }

    }

return result;
}
```

Comment: I'll try and let you know!